# Why is this wrong $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2n+1} - \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2n} = 0$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

I've seen this in many books/videos and i would love to know the reason why it is not true !
$$S_n = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n}$$
$$\frac{1}{2}S_n = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2n}$$
thus : $$S_n - \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2n}  =\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2n+1}$$
Or : $$S_{2n+1}-S_{2n} = 0 $$
But that is not true because it's the power series of  $\space\space log(x+1)\space\space$   for $\space\space x = 1$ and it's not = to 0.
So please tell me what is wrong with this equation !
thanks in advance !

Comment: If you are not cautious, you can pull out anything from the abyss of infinity...

Comment: Your $S_n$ does not make sense. Perhaps you meant $S_n= \sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{n}$. But then if you use this definition, you will clearly see where the problem is.

Comment: @SangchulLee: That is hilarious xD

Comment: sry for the notation eror, i'll fix it right now !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint: How do we treat 
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty}a_n-\lim_{n\to \infty}b_n
$$
where 
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty}a_n=\lim_{n\to \infty}b_n=\infty
$$

Comment: i see what you mean, thank you !

Answer (score 1):

"Playing" with $\infty$ is always dangerous.

So, let me consider
$$a_p=\sum_{n=0}^{p} \frac{1}{2n+1} - \sum_{n=1}^{p} \frac{1}{2n} $$ Now, we have 
$$\sum_{n=0}^{p} \frac{1}{2n+1}=\frac{1}{2}H_{p+\frac{1}{2}}+\log (2)$$
$$\sum_{n=1}^{p} \frac{1}{2n}=\frac{1}{2}H_p$$ where appear harmonic numbers.

Now, using the asymptotics$$H_k=\gamma +\log \left({k}\right)+\frac{1}{2 k}-\frac{1}{12
   k^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{k^4}\right)$$ and further, Taylor series, we should get $$a_p=\log (2)+\frac{1}{4 p}-\frac{3}{16 p^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{p^3}\right)$$

Let us check for $p=10$; we should have 
$$a_{10}=\frac{31730711}{14549535}-\frac{7381}{5040}=\frac{166770367}{232792560}\approx 0.716390$$ while the above expansion would give $$a_{10}\approx \log (2)+\frac{37}{1600}\approx 0.716272$$ For sure, you see how it behaves (and what is the limit) when $p$ becomes larger and larger.

Comment: Yes, it's true that it's converging to log 2 and not 0 ! i can see it. thank you

Comment: @HptunjyPrjkeizg. You are welcome !